# JShell Edit Pad running only one line when accepting

Tags: java, jshell

I'm learning to use jshell, and tried to write a snippet of code in the edit pad.
When hitting accept, if all the code is in the window only the first line is processed and saved. If I close and open the edit pad, all other lines vanish.
I can use the edit pad if I input the lines one at a time and hit accept after every one, but then it's no different than just writing in the command prompt.

I'm using JShell 10.0.2.

Comment: what is your OS?  Try to link to a screenshot.  If you can, put the screenshot directly here by uploading image.  (new accounts can only link to images as I recall.)

Answer (score 0):

Starting `JDK 12`, it runs multiple lines when you hit `Accept` in `JShell Edit Pad`. Just make sure you start fresh `JShell Edit Pad` by resetting as below:

```
/reset
```

[image]